# Java crashes on startup with an UnsupportedCharsetException

Tags: crash, jvm

I'm under Windows7/64, recently, everything related to Java stopped working(Netbeans, Jdownloader...)
Even if i run the command line:

> java -version

i get this exception:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException
```

Any idea about the problem?

Cheers.

Comment: I would simply reinstall the 32-bit and 64-bit installation of Java on your machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're java installation is broken (such that all or critical character sets have been removed), or you changed the default character set on your system to one that doesn't exist or is not recognized by java. I'd start first with reinstalling java, and if that doesn't work then to start looking at the default character set specified by your system or the java properties.

Comment: OK, i'm trying to reinstall java, i'll come back..

Comment: While i'm accepting the question, Jdownloader is loading :=)